# Retrieving SSL certificate details using visual c++

Tags: c++, ssl, visual-c++, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have been trying to find a way to get SSL certificate details using visual C++. I have tried using **winhttp** library but some values are returned as NULL.

Is there any way to get the details of the SSL certificate returned by a web server?

Comment: Try `WinHttpQueryOption(WINHTTP_OPTION_SERVER_CERT_CONTEXT)`, then you can interrogate the `CERT_CONTEXT` using CryptoAPI functions.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. It worked !!